# Interest ( someone ) in ( something )

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

This phrasal verb means to persuade someone when we try offering something.

Examples :

1. Can I **interest** you **in** coffee?
2. Can I **interest** you **in** having a special relationship between us?

Do native speakers use this term when persuading people?
Can I also use the term as in question #2?

Comment: According to the ODO, yes. "*interest* VERB **1.1** (interest someone in) Persuade someone to undertake or acquire (something): *efforts were made to interest her in a purchase*." http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interest Also, "induce to participate". See also, Cambridge Dict Online, "(*with* in) to persuade to do, buy etc ... *Can I interest you in (buying) this dictionary?*" http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/interest_2

Comment: Harrap's essential English Dictionary, 1996, p.501:  
**2** (*formal*) When you ask someone if you can **interest** them in something, you are trying to persuade them to have it, or buy it: *Could I interest you in a glass of wine?* | *Perhaps we can interest you in one of our cut-price holidays?*

Comment: "Could I interest you in a pair of crampons?" (The Guardian, Feb. 04); "In the meantime, might I interest you in some lovely deductions?" (NYT, Feb. 14).

Comment: You can, but you may not, interest me.

Comment: I'd freak out if somebody used example (2) with me, it sounds very pushy, inappropriate (are we already dating?) and dangerously close to being *creepy*. Short story: Nobody uses that line for asking a woman out. The phrase "*Could I interest you in...?*" is often used (not always) with customers/potential buyers.

Answer (score 3):

Well according to [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/can-i-interest-you-in-something) AmEn speakers use this term;

```
Can I interest you in something

› Would you like to buy or take something:
Can I interest you in a cup of coffee?
```

As of question # 2 I believe we do not buy or take special relationships.If you are addressing a lady I will suggest saying something like " would you allow me to persuade you to have a special relationship with me" but then native AmEn speakers know better.

Anyway, with a lady or a guy I prefer " may I" to " can I". Probably it's OK to say " may I interest you in having a special relationship with me", only our native AmEn fellow members can tell both of us.

Comment: The chivalrous and now outdated mode for asking a woman to marry was something like: [*Would you allow me the honour of](https://www.google.it/search?q=Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of+asking+you+out%3F&oq=Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of+asking+you+out%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of%22&tbm=bks) being your husband?* If a man wanted to invite a woman out, he might have said: *Would you allow me the pleasure of going out with you?* But again, it's very formal and harks back to the 19th century.

Comment: Alternatively: [*Could I persuade you to](https://www.google.it/search?q=Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of+asking+you+out%3F&oq=Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of+asking+you+out%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Would+you+allow+me+the+honour+of%22&tbm=bks) come out with me?* But again it's very polite and formal. Nowadays it's more like: "Can I ask you out?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes people do use this phrase but it is somewhat associated with old fashioned style - especially with regard to face to face selling.

Indeed you're likely to find parodies of old style shop interactions 'Could I interest Sir in one of our fine  silk ties...?" If you search Youtube.

I'm pretty sure Monty Python did several.

I would not be surprised if an older person (60 plus) used this phrase with me but someone younger would only use it in jest or parody I think.

The more common use of the verb is in the other format which you correctly distinguish from this 
 ' I am interested in  ...'